# Unable to correctly subset a multiindex column to apply pandas styler

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        ("A", "Current"): [1, 2, 3],
        ("A", "Prev"): [1, 1, 1],
        ("B", "Current"): [7, 8, 9],
        ("B", "Prev"): [5, 4, 3],
    }
)
```

[image]

I am trying to use the pandas style.apply() to format one column relative to another column using my `movement` function below, which checks the value of one 'Current' column against the relevant 'Prev' column.

My dataframe is actually much wider, so I want to iteratively apply() my movement() function over various subsets of columns, changing the colors and reference columns e.g. C Current and Prev, D Current and Prev and so on.

```py
def movement(row, current_col, prev_col, color_one, color_two):
    colors = pd.DataFrame("", index=row.index, columns=row.columns)
    colors[current_col] = np.where(
        (row[current_col] > 0) & (row[current_col] <= 2) & (row[prev_col] > 0),
        f"color:{color_one}",
        f"color:{color_two}",
    )
    return colors

df_style = df.style.apply(
    movement,
    current_col=("A", "Current"),
    prev_col=("A", "Prev"),
    color_one="green",
    color_two="red",
    axis=None,
    subset=[("A", "Current")],
)

df_style.render()
```

This works until I try and pass the subset argument, as I only want the conditional formatting rule to be applied to one column at a time. Including the subset argument like above gives me a key error. I have tried many various of the subset using pd.IndexSlice but I just cannot get it to work.

How can I correctly subset the column with the df.style.apply() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that if `subset=[('A','Current')]`, then there are no other columns remaining and thus `prev_col` can not be equal to `('A','Prev')`.

"Subsetting" only on column `A`, you keep both `Current` and `Previous`, and your code works as expected:

```py
df_style = df.style.apply(
    movement,
    current_col=("A", "Current"),
    prev_col=("A", "Prev"),
    color_one="green",
    color_two="red",
    axis=None,
    subset='A',
)
```

Outputs:

[image]